# Apache2 Dynamic vHost with multiple ServerAlias

Tags: apache, dynamic, dns

I am trying to set up a dynamic vHost, but have run into some trouble.  It will not allow me to set multiple ServerAlias.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias *.com
        ServerAdmin michael.ian.curry@gmail.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/production/html
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

The above vHost only works for '*.com'  i need it to work for 'www.*.com' and '*.com'
I assumed that setting the ServerAlias to  would fix it, but it is not working.

```
ServerAlias *.com www.*.com
```

If you have any insight, please respond

--MichaelCurry

==EDIT 1==

Example redcrusher.com and www.redcrusher.com

==EDIT 2==

The code below does not work either

```
ServerAlias www.*.com *.com
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Figured it out!

'www.*.com' must execute before '*.com'  This is because ServerAlias is setting a dynamic domain and must exist before a "smaller" alias exists.

Example: 'www.*.com', 'dev.*.com', 'asdf.*.com' THEN '*.com'

vHost File [production.conf]:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias www.*.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2/production/html
    ServerAdmin michael.ian.curry@gmail.com
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/production/html
    ServerAdmin michael.ian.curry@gmail.com
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope this helps anyone else that is having this problem!

--MichaelCurry

Answer (score 4):

you must use like this

```
ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com
```

if You want use That Way You Must Follow Order

```
ServerAlias www.*.com *.com
```

the problem is of

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/production/html
```

you Use a Dynamic  VirtualDocumentRoot  that mean

for redcrusher.com  VirtualDocumentRoot  is

```
/var/www/redcrusher/production/html
```

and for www.redcrusher.com VirtualDocumentRoot  is

```
/var/www/www.redcrusher/production/html
```

I think with split  ServerAlias in Three part it solve

```
ServerAlias www.*.com
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/production/html/
ServerAlias *.*.com
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2/production/html/%1 
ServerAlias *.com 
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1/production/html
```

i think should Work

VirtualDocumentRoot :

redcrusher.com

```
/var/www/redcrusher/production/html
```

www.redcrusher.com

```
/var/www/redcrusher/production/html/
```

sub.redcrusher.com

```
/var/www/redcrusher/production/html/sub
```

Comment: Still not working. Added this and t still does not work.  Example: redcrusher.com & www.redcrusher.com

Comment: are you sure bind system is run and config

Comment: Bind is not needed.  Not using a local DNS, using NameCheap as a DNS

Comment: DNS Set Correctly? and Can Get ping from domain ?

Comment: redcrusher.com and www.redcrusher resolve to the same ip addess.

Comment: @michaelcurry I make a change on my answer see it.

Comment: It is going to the directory /vat/www/www/production/html