# How to configure dynamic subdomains for Apache2 on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, dns, subdomain

I need all url mydomain.com, a.mydomain.com, b.mydomain.com, whatever.mydomain.com....
point to the same DocumentRoot, the subdomain is dynamic(maybe have more than hundreds)

Now I have the following lines in 000-default.conf:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mydomain.com
   ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
```

The mydomain.com is work, but all subdomain is not found. 
Can someone help me? thanks so much.....

For example: 
A user register a new account, the new account is "obama" then the url would be "obama.mydoamin.com". The subdomain can be entry when the account create immediately.

Comment: Solved the problem......the problem is not from ubuntu/apache, it's from DNS, so i define DNS ZONE FILE host=*, point=ip

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard sub-domains are possible using Apache virtual hosts.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app1
  ServerName xyz1.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example
  ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/wildcard
  ServerName other.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The first entry will become the default if you don't get an explicit match. So if you had xyz.otherexample.com point to it, it would be caught be xyz1.example.com. You need to turn on the name based virtual hosts with the first entry.

For further details you can also refers to apache documentation [apache Doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/name-based.html)

Comment: but the subdomain is dynamic. user create an account, the system will give  user an url. For example: the new account is "obama" then the url would be "obama.mydoamin.com". so how to achieve this issue?

Comment: you can also refer to this link http://blog.calcatraz.com/wildcard-subdomains-in-apache-1422 in which you can manage it by mod_vhost_alias.so apache's module.

Comment: else go with .htaccess file it will also helpful in your case

Comment: Here is something similar to your requirement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700797/apache2-dynamic-vhost-with-multiple-serveralias