# making Laravel coexist with multiple other LAMP projects using apache virtual host

Tags: php, apache, laravel, virtualhost

I'm trying to make Laravel coexist with other projects on a local installation under /var/www, the current solution I have is to use an alias for the Laravel directory and several other aliases for the other projects.

For instance:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Alias /laravel /var/www/laravel/public
        Alias /other_project /var/www/other_project
        <Directory /var/www/other>
                Order allow,deny
                 allow from all
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
        <Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

the solution above however makes http://localhost and http://localhost/laravel both redirect to Laravel, if I put say an index.php on the root directory of /var/www this is ignored and the Laravel installation is shown instead.

The directory other_project instead works correctly being completely separated from Laravel and showing its contents.

How can I make http://localhost/ show a standard index.php, http://localhost/laravel show a Laravel installation and http://localhost/other_project show another php project??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700797/apache2-dynamic-vhost-with-multiple-serveralias

Comment: the above solution uses different ServerAlias however I'm working on a local installation and can only use localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
```

To

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

That is if you want to display anything form `/var/www`

Comment: If I change the DocumentRoot to /var/www Laravel breaks, I see localhost correctly but as soon as I visit localhost/laravel images are broken and visiting a link inside laravel for instance laravel/login redirects me to localhost/login with a 404 error.

Comment: Try to add another virtualhost where Laravel is going to be the document root. Usually for multiple sites on a single apache, we add multiple VirtualHosts. You may also try to give each virtualhost a `ServerName` and a `ServerAlias` attributes.